# DoS and Serialization

Tags: java, denial-of-service

I got the following message from Fortify static code analyser.

> Incorrect serialization and de-serialization can lead to unpredictable behavior and cause denial of service attacks.

Can anyone explain how this can be serialization and de-serialization can lead to DoS?

Comment: see the part "Preventing Denial-of-Service Attacks" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733135.aspx (the info also applies to Java).

Comment: (This is one of the DoS examples mentioned in the Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html#1-1 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the serialized data is provided by an untrusted client, it can be manipulated.

Let's assume there is a linked list. The attacker can add a **huge number of entries**.

It may even be possible to created invalid serialized data. For example the length field of an array can be set to a very huge number. The server will allocate enough memory to store all elements, although they are never sent.

In some circumstances it is possible to **trigger code that allocates other resources** such as threads or files.

Last but not least there have been classes with [bugs](http://schierlm.users.sourceforge.net/TypeConfusion.html) in their serialization code.